# Determination of equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

Let $m,n$ integers, It can be determined that $3^{n^2-m^2} = 81$, if:

$(1) n-m = 2$

$(2) n+m = 2$

My attempt was:

$3^{n^2-m^2} = 81 \to (n-m)(n+m) =4$, then if $n-m$ or $n+m$ is $2$, the other product will be $2$ too , i.e if $n-m = 2 \to n+m = 4/2 = 2$

Then, my answer **Each one by itself**, but according to the guide the correct answer is $(1), (2) $**Both together**.

The [reason](https://psu.demre.cl/publicaciones/pdf/2020-19-08-01-resolucion-modelo-matematica.pdf)(question $9$) they give is because with $(1)$ we don't know anything about $n + m$ and with $(2)$ we don't know anything about $n-m$.

So, what is wrong with my development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have $$3^{n^2-m^2} = 81 = 3^4$$

In order to have $$n^2-m^2=4$$ you have to have $$(n-m)(n+m)=4$$

If one of the factors is $2$ then the other one has to be $4/2$ which is $2$ as well.

If only one of them is $2$ then the product is not $4$.

Comment: Of course, I was assuming it was $4$ from the beginning. But the other product could take any value. The correct equation must be $(n-m)(n+m) = k$

Answer (score 1):

Since we only have one equation with two variables, even with the restriction that $n,m\in\Bbb Z$, we can start off by trying to write one variable in terms of the other.
\begin{align}
3^{n^2-m^2}&=81\\
3^{n^2-m^2}&=3^4\\
n^2-m^2&=4\\
n^2&=4+m^2\\
n&=\pm\sqrt{4+m^2}
\end{align}

Since $4$ is the only perfect square that is $4$ more than another perfect square (assuming we think $0$ is a perfect square), this gives us $m=0$ as the only value.  So we have $n=\pm 2$ and the solution set to the equation is $\boxed{(m,n)=(0,2) \text{ or } (0,-2)}.$

Thus, it is not enough to know that $n-m=2$.  (Am I understanding the question correctly?)